# Getting started with cfwebsocket

Tags: coldfusion, websocket, coldfusion-2016

I can't seem to get any sample app working. I'm trying to run a simple websocket 101 starter app that does nothing more than log something to console.

I have cfws directory in my webroot `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, and I'm working in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\`.

I have enabled web sockets in the cfadmin, with "use proxy" option, port 8579.

The code I'm running is:

index.cfm:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Example One</title>
         <script language="javascript">
              function messageHandler(msg) {
                  console.log("messageHandler Run");
                 console.dir(msg);
              }
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <h1>Example One</h1>    
    </body>
</html>

<cfwebsocket name="myWS" onMessage="messageHandler" subscribeTo="news">
```

Application.cfc

```
component {
   this.name="cfwack2_1";
   this.wschannels = [{name:"news"}];
}
```

I run the code and there are no errors, but I don't see the expected log in the console.

So far every sample app I've tried does five eighths of nothing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about websockets but your javascript looks fishy.  Function messageHandler expects an argument but the onMessage event of your cfwebsocket tag calls it without one.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo in your Application.cfc. According to [the docs here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-u-z/cfwebsocket.html), it should look like this:

```
component {
   this.name="cfwack2_1";
   this.wschannels=[{name="news"}];
}
```

An `=` (equal sign) instead of a `:` (colon) after `name`.

The documentation also shows that the JavaScript function should accept an event *and* a token value. Here is the example from the documentation.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function mymessagehandler(aevent, atoken) 
    { 
        var message = ColdFusion.JSON.encode(atoken); 
        var txt=document.getElementById("myDiv"); 
        txt.innerHTML +=message +""; 
    } 
</script> 

<cfwebsocket name="mycfwebsocketobject" onmessage="mymessagehandler" subscribeto="news"> 
<cfdiv id="myDiv"></cfdiv>
```

Comment: Nice try, but that didn't make a difference

Comment: The documentation that I referenced also shows that the javascript function is expecting a token attribute. Have you tried that? I will update my answer with the example.